# Group by issue with iSNULL function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do i resolve the group by issue here.

```
SELECT 
    Tcg.ProviderID,
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY , AEenc.StartDateTime , AEenc.EndDateTime),0) + ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY , IPenc.AdmissionDate , IPenc.ENDDate),0) as 'IPBedDays'
FROM #TargetClientGroup Tcg
INNER JOIN AEncounterDetail as AEenc
    ON AEenc.ProviderID = Tcg.ProviderID
INNER JOIN [PEncounterDetail] as IPenc
    ON IPenc.ProviderID = Tcg.ProviderID
--WHERE AEenc.StartDateTime >= @ReportDate
GROUP BY Tcg.ProviderID
```

I am getting an error because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 6):

`ISNULL` is not an aggregation function, and as a consequence, when you're grouping it won't be performing as expected.  I would recommend `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, or `AVG` wrapped around your `ISNULL` statement dependant on what you're trying to achieve with your query.

Comment: This looks like a good work around. And it workes fine for the solution. Thanks for hte help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT  Tcg.ProviderID
    ,   IPBedDays = SUM(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, AEenc.StartDateTime, AEenc.EndDateTime), 0) + ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, IPenc.AdmissionDate, IPenc.EndDate), 0))
FROM #TargetClientGroup Tcg
JOIN AEncounterDetail AEenc ON AEenc.ProviderID = Tcg.ProviderID
JOIN [PEncounterDetail] IPenc ON IPenc.ProviderID = Tcg.ProviderID
--WHERE AEenc.StartDateTime >= @ReportDate
GROUP BY Tcg.ProviderID
```